# Image size to fit column width from SQL database in datagridview C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `datagridview` with a few columns, one of which contains images. I'm getting all the required data from the database to the datagridview but the image is not showing completely, how to make image size completely in datagridview cell?

This is the code I have so far.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [**DataGridViewImageColumn**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) to show the complete image in a cell.

There is also a property where one can **[DataGridViewImageCellLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecelllayout(v=vs.110).aspx)** zoom and stretch the image in the cell if you need to.

Example:[image]

https://johnroach.io/2012/01/13/how-to-add-images-to-datagridview-cell-using-c-and-windows-forms/